# Arabic data is not appearing right in excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I have an excel sheet that contains data that I exported from an Oracle database, and now when I try to open this file from another machine (my laptop), the data appears as strange letters, like Chinese characters, although Arabic is downloaded on my laptop.

How can I read this file?

Comment: When you say exported, how did you do that? Are you sure you have the right file?

Comment: @soandos Excel supports many different types of database connections using [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC)

Comment: I know, but not my question. If he is just trying to read a raw oracle file, it would be unreadable in excel. That is what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and what I was seeing was unknown charcaters like this

- ????? ???? ????? ????
  or like this
- ØªÙ…ÙˆÙŠÙ„ Ø¨Ø¯ÙˆÙ† ØªØ­ÙˆÙŠÙ„ Ø±Ø§ØªØ¨

The Solution

- Create notepad.txt file

  Copy the unknown characters in it, and then hit "ctrl+s" to save the file

  Change the extension from .txt to .srt

  Open the file using Microsoft Word

  It will open with small windows in Word showing the encoding of the original form of the unknown characters, it automatically converts them to understandable Arabic language.

  Just in case the if the automatically converting didn't work chose from the encoding list, choose "UTF-8" or "Arabic (Windows)" "Auto Select" and it will convert the unknown characters to Arabic characters

  Take the Arabic data copy and paste them back in the Excel file.

Mission Accomplished :D